# Display is wrong at startup until I click on "display" then it's fine? -dual montors Unity 2D

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, 2d

My display is wrong after it reboots. I then go to "displays" and without touching anything else it fixes itself. I then close out the "display" function and the resolutions are correct and the monitors are not mirroring each other.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 in Unity 2D mode. I have dual monitors setup.

How can I fix this so I don't have to open up the "displays" every-time I reboot?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem and solved it by editing the **monitors.xml** file in your .config folder ([Ubuntu 11.10 dual monitor set up instructions](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ubuntu-11-10-dual-monitors-set-up-not-saving/))

These are the steps you should try:

1. Open up a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Go to your config folder (cd ~/.config)
3. Open up your file for editing (gedit monitors.xml)
4. Ensure that `<primary>yes</primary>` is on the correct output/monitor (and `<primary>no</primary>` is on the other)
5. Ensure that `<clone>no</clone>` is included on the third line

This may not affect the log in screen though as LightDM has its own monitor settings (annoyingly). Hopefully this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using the graphical interface "Display" in the Ubuntu Settings (I simply changed a random parameter to let it save the shown configuration and then everything started to work again properly).

Ps. The answer provided by captain_G unfortunately doesn't work.
It seems that the monitor.xml file is mainly ignored (even though I change something everything come back to the previous situation at startup).
However, after the changes made through the graphical interface, my monitor.xml file contains the following configuration:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="eDP-1">
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x06a9</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-1">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-2">
      </output>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
      <clone>yes</clone>
      <output name="eDP-1">
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x06a9</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>120</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-1">
          <vendor>PHL</vendor>
          <product>0xc0c5</product>
          <serial>0x00000626</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>1920</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-2">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```